# How to omit sections from table of contents in R Markdown with officedown

Tags: r, r-markdown, officedown

I am drafting an rmd that needs a Table of Contents and needs to be knitted to Word. I am using the officedown package and while I can get a TOC, I need to have the table not include the Section header for the table of contents. I have this:

```
---
output:
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    reference_docx: word_styles_ref_01.docx
---



{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.cap = TRUE)
library(officedown)
library(officer)

<!---CHUNK_PAGEBREAK--->    
# Table of Contents 
<!---BLOCK_TOC--->    
<!---CHUNK_PAGEBREAK--->



My report starts here.

# Heading 1
My report starts here.

## Heading 2
And I have this next subsection.
```

But I do not want "Table of Contents" to be repeated in the actual table of contents. In the above code it is repeated in the word doc with the page number. Is there a way to not include this in the TOC?

Answer (score 1):

Per https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/toc-unlisted.html, simply add {.unlisted .unnumbered} after the header.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).